# What is the word to describe speaking in the negative perspective?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Instead of saying "It is sunny", someone says "It is not cloudy" or "It is the opposite of cloudy".

Is there a word to describe the last 2 sentences to mean speaking in the negative perspective?

Comment: "It's sunny " isn't the opposite of "It's not cloudy".  We can have a cloudless sky at night.  Also, the opposite of "cloudy" is "cloudless", not "sunny".

Comment: That's not the point of the question though.

Comment: You seem to be describing something like [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes). Is that the term you're looking for?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages   It relates to your sample sentence and that's why it's just a comment and not an answer. No offense meant.

Comment: Negatives are present everywhere in speech. They don't require and don't have any special terminology.